# Does the Google Reader API token expire?

Tags: google-reader

Ok, so I have an app that hooks in pretty deeply with GR's "api".

Everything is working nicely, BUT lately I have been getting permission denied returns from Google. If I log out of GR and log back in with my app it all starts working again. This leads me to believe that the authorization token GR gives you when you log in expires after a month or so.

Has anyone else run into this? If you have, what is the best way to deal with it. I REALLY don't want to have to store people's Google account and password to reauthorize from time to time.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ClientLogin authentication method provides tokens that expire after two weeks. The OAuth method's tokens never expire.

Comment: I may be ignorant, but I have never seen any documentation about the unofficial Google Reader API supporting OAuth. Where can I learn about that?

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication and more generally http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi.

Comment: Other useful links I use (fougrapi is a great forum to ask your questions, but these ones have more structured info - more like an API doc): http://www.chrisdadswell.co.uk/android-coding-example-authenticating-clientlogin-google-reader-api/, http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI, http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/10/16/using-the-google-reader-api-part-2

Comment: do you know the timeout for edit tokens, got from api/0/token?

Comment: Edit tokens expire after 30 minutes.