# Google Reader API mark as read

Tags: google-reader

I'm trying to mark an item as read using Google reader API.

I'm calling:
    https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag

with POST parameters:

```
i=tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/abd8ef2540e2948a
a=user/-/state/com.google/read
ac=edit
s=feed/http://9gag.com/rss/site/feed.rss
T=//XyTiEe7pm4RZtwtO2KKTfw
```

and I get Error 400: Bad Request

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is often thrown when your access token(`T` parameter) is expired. Access token is a short-lived token, it expires after 30 minutes (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853435/does-the-google-reader-api-token-expire#comment7388599_5853699)).

I think you should get a new token and take one more try. I just tried this API method out, and it works.

One more note: your `ac=edit` parameter is not necessary here. This parameter is used in the [subscription API](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/ApiSubscriptionEdit), not in edit tags API. So you can easily remove it.